# PHP Session for a login site - theoretical

Tags: php, session

Today I started learning about sessions. Our first task is to create a small website, a login site and a members site. If you successfully log in, you get transferred to the members' site. If you try to access the members' site without logging in, you will be transferred to the login page.

Our teacher wants us to, on every page, have a control script running. This script, as I understand it, should take what I wrote in my form (the form which I log in to), and check if it is equal to a user. If it is correct, a session starts. The thing that bothers me is that this is running on every page of the website. Is this not very efficient. Every time the user redirects themselves, the server needs to process the login information again, and again.

I did some researching on a session and I found another way of doing things. Every page automatically starts a session. When a user logs in, the server checks the login information. If the information is correct a session variable is assigned a user ID. When the user goes to another page on the website, a script checks if this user ID is set. If it is set, then the user has logged in if it is not set, the user has not logged in. If the user logs out. The session is destroyed, meaning that every session variable is lost. Now, the server does not need to process the same login information every time a new page is loaded.

Is my way of thinking acceptable? Or are there other ways of doing this that is better?

Comment: Yes, that's in a nutshell how a typical session based login system works.

Comment: The way that you described it is how I've always done my login scripts, I don't know why your teacher told you to do so otherwise but keep in mind that you should follow your teacher's instructions for the appropriate grade.

Comment: I think to be honest you probably misunderstood what you thought your teacher was saying

Comment: You are correct; most login systems work the way you are thinking. Sending the credentials fresh with every page load is a valid way to handle logins for some kinds of system, but is typically used without sessions. A session is only useful if it allows you to persist that kind of data; there is no value to having it if the credentials are refreshed on \every page load.

Comment: You should discuss this with your teacher, and make sure that you've understood what they're trying to show you and why. For example, it's possible that they are getting you to write it this way as a starting point so that they can then move onto the next lesson and show you that you don't need to submit the fields each time. In that case, you may be just a step ahead of the lesson rather than the lesson being wrong.

Comment: The more practical problem with the way you understood it is that you'll have a hard time passing the information from the form with every request again and again to the server…

Comment: Thanks to all of your responses!

Answer (score -1):

How php `$_SESSION` variable works.

On every single page you would like the user to be logged in to view, you will need to include `session_start();` right at the top of the page.

for example dashboard would need a user to be logged in to view it,
you would do something like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['userID'] = 1; // setting the variable as userID 1

   if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
      header("Location: ../Login");  // redirects to login page
   } else {
     // do something here if the session is set
   }
 ?>
```

`isset()` returns `1` or `0` if the variable has data inside of it

basically you would call the user information after the login and set the `$_SESSION['userID']` to the user id in your database

Comment: This makes no sense. Setting `$_SESSION['userID']` and then testing if it is set will always be true.

Comment: @Michel i added that to show the OP, how to set the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!